# Pandas remove row in df2 based on string in another column in df1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes where `id`, `first_seen`, `last_seen` are strings and `days_since_fire` is an int.  I would like to remove the `id` from df2 where the `last_seen` in df1 equals '2020-05-02'

```
df1
    id  first_seen  last_seen   days_since_fire
0   001 2020-05-01  2020-05-01  0
1   002 2020-05-01  2020-05-01  0
2   003 2020-05-02  2020-05-02  0

df2
    id
0   001
1   003
2   002
3   004
```

Desired outcome:

```
df2
    id
0   001
2   002
3   004
```

Comment: chekc with isin

Comment: already did can't see an example with 2 dataframes @YOBEN_S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

```
df2=df2.loc[~df2.id.isin(df1.loc[df1.last_seen=='2020-05-02','id'])].copy()
df2
Out[393]: 
   id
0   1
2   2
3   4
```

Comment: or change `==` to `!=` to save the `~` :)